# "User xxx has no home directory" error with Emacs installed through linuxbrew

Tags: linux, emacs, linuxbrew

Installed emacs through linuxbrew on CentOS 7. After run "emacs" from terminal, I got this error message:

```
User xxx has no home directory
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on Red Hat 7.6. It seemed to be caused by incorrect expansion of the `~USER` syntax by `expand-file-name`.

As mentioned [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/34022/error-initialization-user-has-no-home-directory), the solution is to start emacs with `--user ''`, which should expand to the correct home directory.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on old Redhat servers if I use either homebrew's emacs or emacs binary obtained by building latest emacs + Homebrew libraries. I temporary fix this issue by compiling latest Emacs using system library i.e commenting out path setup for homebrew then compile Emacs. If you do not want to compile Emacs manually then try these automated build scripts https://github.com/hungptit/athemacs.

Answer (score -1):

Well, if `xxx` doesn't have home directory then create one for it. `sudo usermod --home *new home directory* xxx`. Then logout and log back in.

Comment: I am using that user, it has lots of things there. Reboot the computer, still get the same error.

Comment: Are you sure home directory is defined for this user? Try to run `cat /etc/passwd | grep xxx | cut -d ':' -f 6` and see that it indeed shows the home directory of xxx.

Comment: Just notice that the user is not a local user. It is managed by `centrify`. But that user can do normal operation on the local machine.